# OpenVPN Access Server hangs after a while

Tags: openvpn

We have an OpenVPN Access Server (OpenVPN AS) installed on one of our bare metal servers. The service runs fine, but after a while—indefinitely, maybe hours, maybe a day—it just hangs. The process is still there, but connection can’t be estabished, and the web interface can’t be accessed (timed out).

These are the steps I took, all failed to solve the issue:

- Allow OpenVPN-related ports in `iptables`
- Disallow OpenVPN to modify `iptables`
- Shut down `iptables` (!)
- Switch OpenVPN protocol to TCP / UDP.

There’s [this post](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic14283.html) whose OP had a very similar issue, but his cause was lacking of memory. Mine is not the case, since we have a lot of memory left (it’s a 8GB of RAM box).

Anyone here has encountered this before and can share a solution/direction?

Comment: No I don't think it crashed – the process is still there listening to ports. Also, OpenVPN is not using much of RAM, since we're only testing the service with max 2 clients at a time.